# MySQL's equivalent of Oracle Rtrim?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am trying to have in MySQL the same effect as of Oracle's `Rtrim`.

```
oracle> RTRIM('Tech6372', '0123456789')
Result: 'Tech'
```

As you can see Oracle regards the second parameter as a list of characters to be removed, not as a substring to be removed.

This is different from the following in MySQL:

```
mysql> SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'xyz' FROM 'barxxyz');
Result: 'barx'
```

Is there a neat way to get MySQL to do the same thing as Oracle does here?

Comment: Are you able to add User Defined Functions (UDF) such as https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp however it requires the creation of a UDF.  If so then regExp_Replace seems like it may serve your needs the best.  additional support: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Comment: How do I add a UDF to the Database?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html for instructions from mySQL